# Solution to this problem?

Tags: arithmetic

Could you solve this question for me?
If $10$ years are added to $3/5$ of the age of John, he will be $4$ years younger to the present age of his elder brother who will be $25$ years. What is the present age of John?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is normally recommended that you show some working as this appears to be a homework question.

Comment: Sorry I am very weak in mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the present age of John, then
\begin{align}
\frac{3}{5}x+10&=25-4\\
\frac{3}{5}x+10&=21\\
\frac{3}{5}x&=11\\
x&=\frac{5}{3}\cdot11\\
x&=\frac{55}{3}
\end{align}
Therefore, the present age of John is $\cfrac{55}{3}$ years.

Comment: Thanks!for your reply V-MOY

Comment: My pleasure @KarimGhazali. I'm glad you're happy. Thanks also for accepting my answer. (✿◠‿◠)

Comment: @KarimGhazali Why did you take back your vote from my answer!? You can only accept one answer. (╥﹏╥)

Comment: Sorry I did not know we can only vote up one answer thanks for telling. It's back there again.

Comment: @KarimGhazali It's OK. If you have enough reputation (15 points), you can vote up back our answers. George's answer also deserves vote up. (ô‿ô)

Answer (score 2):

Treat it as an equation. Let $x$ be the present age of John. Now $$\frac{3}{5}x+10=21$$ I'll leave the rest up to you.